# "aus", "outside" or "from"?

Tags: translation, phrase

In this sentence:

> Nehmen Sie den Wein aus Deutschland.

what would "aus" mean? "outside" or "from" ? And is this a question? I see the verb and pronoun are switched.

In other words, should I translate this as

> 1. "Do you take wine from Germany?"
> 2. "Do you take wine outside Germany?"
> 3. "You take wine from Germany"
> 4. "You take wine outside Germany"

Even 4 different phrases I'm unsure of :/

Comment: *from*, and it's the imperative mood.

Comment: oh, I haven't studied that yet so I didn't know it. Thanks! If you make it an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the (in your example omitted) punctuation. If the waiter asks you

> Nehmen Sie den Wein aus Deutschland?

he means: "Do you take the wine from Germany?" If he says

> Nehmen Sie den Wein aus Deutschland!

he means: "Do take the wine from Germany! I suggest it!". In either case, the wine is supposed to come from Germany. If one talks about exporting wine, then another construction is necessary, such as

> Wir exportieren Wein aus Deutschland heraus. (grammatically correct, but bad style)

This does not necessarily imply the wine is from Germany, but may as well.

Comment: Thanks! German is quite hard for me right now. Constance, patience and some easy subtitled videos on youtube are helping me greatly.. but time is also required :)

Comment: One doesn't use `exportieren aus somewhere heraus`. If you export something, you name the country you export *to*. If you import something, you name the contry you import *from*: `Wir importieren Wein aus Deutschland.`

Comment: @Toscho: I agree. I was pointing out the grammatical structure, that this sentence has very bad style is something else :-|

Answer (score 0):

Many, many words don't have a single translation into another language. I think "ablegen" has over a dozen totally different translations from German to English. "Aus" is not far off :-)

"aus " means "originating from ". You take the meaning and translate it to the best possible English you can :-) "from Germany" seems fine. "Aus" as a single word would be the location of a ball leving the playing field (tennis, soccer). That's about the only time I would translate it as "outside". "Aus" means "over": Der Film ist aus. The movie is over. Die Schule ist aus. School is over. "Going out" is "ausgehen" ("wir gehen aus").